# How do I link my godaddy domain name to Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I've searched around and I still can't find anything on how to do this. Ideally I would like to know how to link up multiple domain names as I am now using SDK 1.3.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on what Dave has said.  When you deploy your app to Azure, it gets an address that looks something like this:
myazureapplication.cloudapp.net

Per the instructions on the page here, http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47610 or any other dozen pages that come up when one googles "CNAME godaddy", you want to point your domain record hosted at GoDaddy to myazureapplication.cloudapp.net (or whatever your app happens to be).  You're not pointing to IP, but to domain name, wihch is why its a CNAME record

HTH

Comment: To be fair... this is now the #2 result for 'azure godaddy' on Google, with 13K views.  Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 2):

There's a service called DNS Azure that updates your A records automatically. See [here](http://dnsazure.com/)

Comment: I use this for my service using a lot of domains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply creating a CNAME entry for all of your custom domain names, to point to your .cloudapp.net Windows Azure deployment name?